# How to redirecct to record detail page using ltng out app and flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, lightning-out

I'm using a `ltng:outApp` that opens a `lightning:flow` from a visualforce page. The flow takes multiple inputs from the user and creates a record on a custom object. When the flow finishes I'm trying to redirect the user to the newly created record detail page. I've tried creating a simple aura lightning component:

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.invoke}" />
</aura:component>
```

js.controller:

```
invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
    var record = component.get("v.recordId");
    var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    redirect.setParams({
        "recordId": record,
    });
    redirect.fire();
}
```

The console log shows the invoke function being entered and the variable holds the correct record id value, but the `navigateToSObject` doesn't fire. Is it possible to redirect to the record detail page after the flow finishes using ltng:outApp from visualforce? Is there a different approach that should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[force:navigateToSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation) is only available in select experiences:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce mobile app, and Aura-based Experience Builder sites.

Note that Lightning Out is *not* a supported experience. Instead, just use `window.location.href` (or `window.top.location.href` if in an iframe).